# AnyEvent::DBI and database reconnection

Tags: mysql, perl, event-handling, database-connection, dbi

I'm using AnyEvent::DBI in a singleton package, and when there is no activity in the database / queries etc after many hours, I get this error while trying to issue a query:

```
DBD::mysql::st execute failed: MySQL server has gone away at /usr/local/share/perl/5.10.1/AnyEvent/DBI.pm line 98.
```

A simple approach is to: connect to DB ==> Issue query ==> Close connection.
this way is what I usually use when I'm working with DBI.

The issue in my case is that I cant find a way to re-connect to the database using AnyEvent::DBI, except from creating a new AnyEvent::DBI instance (new).

Any suggestions would be great!

Answer (score 2):

As per the DBD::mysql documentation on CPAN, you want to use:

```
$dbh->{mysql_auto_reconnect} = 1;
```

Here is the link to the reference:

http://metacpan.org/pod/DBD::mysql

Answer (score 1):

In MySQL there's a [`wait_timeout`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_wait_timeout) variable that sets the duration of non-interactive connections.

For long-running connections you can try to alter that value ( default = 28800 ), to a more suitable one.

`wait_timeout` value can be updated with a simple query

```
mysql> SET SESSION wait_timeout = 50000;
```

and retrieved with another one

```
mysql> SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'wait_timeout';
```

Comment: Since I have no idea how much time the DB will be in a non-activity state, I cant really know how much seconds to set the wait_timeout, so I guess, connecting and reconnecting to the DB is a better solution?

Comment: @soulSurfer2010 DB connection are expensive; have you already tried to  wrap `execute()` code inside an `eval {}`, block ( with option  `RaiseError => 1` )? Checking `$@` after `execute()` could give an opportunity to reconnect.

Comment: The problem is, that I dont know how to reconnect in AnyEvent::DBI. If I were using DBI directly, I probably have figured out a away by now.

Comment: You need to set up error handling using the on_error construction callback to handle database disconnection errors. Just reconnect and recreate your handle. You could get around it by generating a timer to SELECT 1 against the database every so often as a keepalive, but going the other way will also handle reconnecting in the event of the sql server restarting, network issues, etc.

Comment: @MarcoDeLellis with MySQL DB connections are really cheap. It's not like Oracle and MS SQL where they are expensive.

Comment: @Oesor  the issue with on_error is that I will need to use 'new' to create a new instance of AnyEvent::DBI, the package is singleton, and it will destroy the first instance, I need a way to reconnect using the already available instance